# MS Excel 2016: How to get the AVERAGE of numbers over large number of discrete ranges?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

I have some data spread across 6500+ rows and 12 columns. Some of the columns have values from a set of 3 numbers (input columns), while other columns have all unique values (output columns).

I am using Excel filters on input columns to filter out some rows based on a particular sets of input. I believe filters in excel just hides the rows which don't satisfy the filter. I need to get the average of the filtered output columns. The filtered data does not have continuous or uniform placement across the rows, so I cannot specify the range (easily) to use the average formula.

How can I obtain the average of the filtered rows?

Sample Data - [Link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1R8nD-na1ATebO3R5JWx0lmr6pTNbDgOPrlOaIKbSOUY/edit?usp=sharing)

Sample Data Explaination - Column A and B (input columns) takes its value from a particular set (namely- {5,10,15} and {20,40,60} respectively). Column C and D (output columns) have unique values in all the cells. Suppose I put up the filter like-

On Column A filter all rows with `value=5`. This filters out the rows 1,2,7,10. Now I wish to get the AVERAGE on these filtered rows of values in columns C and D.

Comment: Please provide some sample data so we can see exactly what you are after and properly answer your question.

Comment: @KevinAnthonyOppegaardRose added some random data with the same form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is `=SUBTOTAL(1,...)` . It only takes into account cells which are visible.

E.g.

```
=SUBTOTAL(1,C1:C12)
=SUBTOTAL(1,C:C)
=SUBTOTAL(1,D1:D12)
=SUBTOTAL(1,D:D)
```

SUBTOTAL is a function that lets you perform different kinds of aggregation calculations (e.g., SUM, AVERAGE, COUNT, MAX, etc.), as well as selecting whether or not to include manually hidden values.  The first parameter specifies which aggregation function you want, as well as whether to ignore manually hidden values.  For AVERAGE, a parameter value of `1` includes hidden values, `101` excludes hidden values.  Values hidden via filters are always excluded, so either `1` or `101` works for this example.  You can also include a list of non-contiguous ranges, it is not limited to a single range specification.  For more explanation of what you can do with SUBTOTAL, see [this link](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-subtotal-function)

Answer (score 0):

Put `=IF($D$16=A1,C1,"")` in F1 and drag until F12.

Then, put `=AVERAGE(F:F)` in E16.

And enter the value "5" in D16.

Done.

p/s : use if(), or() or and() if you have to meet more than one condition. Then use average() to get your desired outcome.

Hope it helps. ( :